# sqlAlchemy dynamic where clause

Tags: dynamic, sqlalchemy, where-clause

I have an array of dictionaries that contains an array for each value. The values of each dictionary are the conditions for an update where clause. Since the length of each array in the dictions is variable I need to be able to dynamically create the where clause.

I'd like to do something like below.

```
sqlAlUpdateList = []
indexHash = [ {1: [1, 6, 11]}, {2: [7, 12]}, {3: [3, 8, 13, 74]} 

for (key, values) in indexHash.iteritems():
  stmt = xtable.update().value(xtable.c.ykey=key).
           where(or_(xtable.c.id == values))
  sqlAlcUpdateList.append(stmt)

for sqlAlcCommand in sqlAlcUpdateList:
  conn.execute(sqlAlcCommand)
```

I know this could be split into multiple update commands but I would like to create one command.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no reason to prefer one single sentence. You're assigning different values to different rows, so I think they are separated actions. But if someone could correct me I'd like to know how to do it!